# How expensive is cross correlation in mobile app

Tags: android, ios, performance, signal-processing

Has anybody tried to do continuous `Cross Correlation` using FFT in a mobile app?

I am trying to do a Cross Correlation on two signals with length of 512 samples and this operation is done every second. It seems that this takes a lot of memory. The way I have implemented Cross Correlation is using `FFT`, where I take FFT of two incoming signals, multiply them and then take inverse FFT.

Has anybody done something similar?

Comment: cant you try and profile it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done profiling. For each FFT, it takes about 3 ms. So for one cross correlation, it will take about 10 ms, and that will be done every second. Is it too expensive? Will it drain the battery too fast if the app runs for hours?

Comment: I am far from an expert in mobile devices, but I think that if you make any device do anything every second, it will have a big impact in the battery life. You can also test this on a mobile device easily. put hte code and see when it shuts

Comment: Yes, I will have to try this definitely but wanted to know if others have encountered such problem. Thanks for your replies :)

Comment: Removing the MATLAB tag as this has nothing to do with MATLAB.